# Store plupload file list in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, plupload

I'm building a web application where I want the user to be able to pick files on multiple pages and then upload all at once. My plan is to use `window.localStorage` to store the files and then iterate through that list and upload.

I have successfully saved the file object array to localStorage, but when I try to manually add them to the queue with `uploader.files.push(file)` (documentation says files is an array of file objects) nothing is uploaded.

Is there a way to manually build the upload queue?

Another acceptable solution would be to store a reference to a local file in localStorage. From what I'm reading I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure browser security doesn't allow you to do that. Is rebuilding this as a single page app so that you can use a single instance for all your file uploads too late at this point in your development?

Comment: I was able to store images persistently using HTML5's file system API, without Pluploader.